# contenteditable no detection image

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, contenteditable

please help me..

I have contenteditable issues, especially on image detection

I use this code :

```
function getnode() {
  var node, selection;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = getSelection();
    node = selection.anchorNode;
  }
  if (!node && document.selection) {
    selection = document.selection;
    var range = selection.getRangeAt ?
      selection.getRangeAt(0) :
      selection.createRange();
    node = range.commonAncestorContainer ?
      range.commonAncestorContainer :
      range.parentElement ? range
      .parentElement() : range.item(0);
  }
  if (node) {
    return (node.nodeName == "#text" ? node.parentNode : node);
  }
}
```

jquery :

```
$(function() {
  $("#editor").bind('click', function(e) {
    var $node = $(getnode());

    if ($node.is('a')) {
      alert("Yes I am link");
    }

    if ($node.is('b')) {
      alert("Yes I am bold");
    }

    if ($node.is('img')) {
      alert("IMAGE READY");
    } else {
      $("#editor").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pjus4ace/)** : Please help me, to find the way

Thank you in advance

Comment: any reason why you are not using `e.target`?

Comment: What **exactly** is your issue? I just tried your fiddle and it seems to run fine.

Comment: @gus27 There is no notification after adding an image and clicking on it that it is an image, so probably the error is with the `getnode()` function, not returning the correct node

Comment: @Icepickle E.target I use in the replacement code for alerts for example taking data a link to the input area

I forgot to delete it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to fix your problem would be to **not** use your own getnode function, but allow the element to come from the click eventhandler by means of the target property.

Changing your code to this works perfectly, at least, for the scenarios I have tried

```
$("#editor").bind('click', function (e) {
    var $node =  $( e.target );
    if ($node.is('a')) {
        alert("Yes I am link");
    }
    if ($node.is('b')) {
        alert("Yes I am bold");
    }
    if ($node.is('img')) {alert("IMAGE READY");
    } else {
        $("#editor").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Icepickle this my demo  [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pjus4ace/2/)